# How to make a div fill the parent element

Tags: html, css

Whenever I style a DIV to:

```
.div {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

I start struggling with setting the div width to fit/ wrap the entire width of the parent element. If I set to `width: 100%;` stretches across the whole page. `max-width`, `min-width` all behave the same way. How can I resolve this so that a div elements fits perfectly across the parent element?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: If you get rid of `position: fixed;` and `z-index: 9999;` it will go full width on its own - that's the behaviour of block elements like divs. You don't need any styles to get a div to go full width of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Try : `position: relative; display: block` on the parent element. .

Width % scale on the first ascendant **WITH** `position: relative`.

**EDIT:** As mentionned by @David Wilkinson this won't work with %width since they are set according to the window size.
However, you might want to try : `width: inherit` (on the fixed bloc and any bloc between the set sized parent and the fixed bloc).

http://codepen.io/Carele/pen/ezBbwV
Working here

Comment: Haha thanks. I didn't think the width wouldn't work too, until you proved me wrong

Answer (score 1):

Remember that when you declare an element as `position: fixed`, you're taking it out of the "normal" flow of a document - so don't expect normal rules to apply... Take this example:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fixed">
    FIX ME!
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, even though the div with class `fixed` it still goes beyond the width of its parent element when I set its position to 100%...

To mimick what you're trying to do, try another approach with `position: absolute` on the child element and `relative` on the parent:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.fixed {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fixed">
    FIX ME!
  </div>
</div>
```

NOTE - you may need to add some top padding to the parent element so the child element doesn't overlap the parent's content... If you also want the child div to appear at the very top of the document, you'll also need to make sure the parent div is at the start of the document.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. However an absolute positionning would not quite have the same result...

Comment: @Carele No, it does have some drawbacks for sure. Every situation is different so I thought I'd explain why the behaivour is happening :)